# How to use client side functionality on EJS page

Tags: node.js, ejs, client-side

After spending a few hours, I could not figure out the best practise to use the 'client-side' functionality on EJS page. The scenario is stated below:

1. I am using express (NodeJS) and using the EJS to render the
   Landing page (along with the other functionality). Initially, I was
   struggling to use JQuery but I manage to require it to the 'app.js'
   (definitely, not the best practice but could not find alternative
   solution hence this question). So, coming to the original question. I
   want to use some the client-side scripting on the EJS page but as
   that page has server-side code not entirely sure how to use client
   side scripting on it (JQuery/Javascript, i,e. on scroll do that
   etc.).
2. My header.ejs file contains some menu items which I want to be dynamic, i.e. top menu bar to be sticky but as that navbar is in the header.ejs file not sure how can I do that from client-side. Currently, I could not call that do that from the one EJS file to another EJS, see below.

```
    // Sticky bar
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application Read this article

Comment: This link does not work

Answer (score 0):

When you use js files in ejs, it is like you don't use ejs or nodejs. It's just static files. And you can't use npm package.

Comment: thanks @litleCodeur, does that mean if  I should include that client-side code in JS file and include in EJS file? and that would work at client-side?

Comment: Yes with a <script></script> tag